# console.log() is not working on all browser

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, console.log

I've recently had a strange issue, where `console.log` doesn't output anything if used inside my code but work fine using directly in the console or using `window.console.log`.

```
window.console.log(console);
window.console.log(window.console);
console.log("test1"); // (won't work)
window.console.log("test2");
```

Ouput:

[image]

If i define console myself the console *before* the code:

```
var console = window.console;
window.console.log(console);
window.console.log(window.console);
console.log("test1");
window.console.log("test2");
```

Ouput:

[image]

And the strangest thing, if i define console myself *after* the code

```
window.console.log(console);
window.console.log(window.console);
console.log("test1");
window.console.log("test2");
var console = window.console;
```

Ouput:

[image]

Note before answering:

1. It's not a browser-specific issue because the output is the same on every browser (i've checked on chrome/firefox/safari/opera).
2. It's not being overridden because a log of `console` & `window.console` return the same exact object (see screenshot).

Comment: If this is happening, you're probably doing something wrong. I just can't seem to reproduce it, so your code must be overwriting something or be in the strangest of scopes where window for some reason isn't the "global" scope etc.

Comment: Following what @adeneo said, what you got if you type `this` in your console?

Comment: What does `window.console.log(console.log.toString());` show?

Comment: @epascarello it show `function log() { [native code] }`

Comment: Could you post a link to your full code?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a live example for this, but i can try to explain my setup. 

the code in my example is used at the top of a file call `app.js`, use simply at `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` in my html. they rest of the code is a traditional backbone/marionette application use for a phonegap application. I'm using livereload & JS sourceMapping in  my workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the amazing features of the JavaScript. The `var` directive is processed on the pre-execution stage. So this code:

```
function foo() {
    window.console.log(console);
    var console = window.console;
    window.console.log(console);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function foo() {
    var console;
    window.console.log(console); // console is local variable and undefined
    console = window.console;
    window.console.log(console);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason why.. In our grunt uglify function (grunt-contrib-uglify), we use the `drop_console` options for compress:

```
uglify: {
    options: {
      compress: {
          drop_console: true
      }
    }, 
// ...
```

Which obviously drop any appearance of `console` but strangely doesn't drop `window.console`.